Why does an HTTPS URL override an HTTP URL when setting up listeners in .NET Core?
Can someone explain why setting an HTTPS URL when building a web app overrides the HTTP settings?
I have the following code which works just fine:
var webApplication = WebApplication.CreateBuilder().Build();
webApplication.Urls.Add("http://*:5002");
webApplication.RunAsync();

When I use Postman to communicate, I have no trouble finding the web application on port 5002.
But when I add an HTTPS port:
var webApplication = WebApplication.CreateBuilder().Build();
webApplication.Urls.Add("http://*:5002");
webApplication.Urls.Add("https://*:500");
webApplication.RunAsync();

The application stops listening on port 5002 and actively refuses the connection.

What about port 500?

The HTTPS port 500 works, but the application stops listening on HTTP port 5002. Remove the line with "https://*:500" and the application starts listening on HTTP:5002 again.

What happens when you switch the order? Do not delete, simply switch so 5002 goes last.

Order makes no difference.

Can you write a minimal reproducible example and post it on GitHub? I am morbidly curious now.

Think I figured it out. The code above works on my development machine, but not at the customer site and not a virgin machine. Swapping the order of the URL declarations didn't change things at all and, as it turns out, nothing works on the customer machine or the virgin machine with this set of URLs.
Once I downloaded Visual Studio to the virgin machine, it was pretty clear that the SSL was failing without a trusted 'localhost' certificate to satisfy the SSL handshake. Not only that, but it appears that once the SSL certificate verification fails, not only does the HTTPS traffic fail to listen, but so does the normal HTTP traffic.
